# Passing type information to function in lieu of virtual template function C++

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, overloading

I have a base class which implements the following:

```
struct Consumer
{
    template <typename T>
    void callback(T msg) { /*null implementation */ }
};
```

I then have a class implement this:

```
struct Client : public Consumer
{
     void callback(Msg1 msg);
     void callback(Msg2 msg);
     void callback(Msg3 msg);
};
```

The issue is I have a container of Client objects treated as Consumer* and I can't think of a way to get these Consumer objects to call the derived functions. My intended functionality is to have multiple Clients each of which implement an overloaded function for each Msg class that means something to them and the rest of the calls simply call the null implementation in the base class

Any thoughts how I can get the derived class to be called? Right now I need to implement every overloaded function in Consumer and mark them as virtual.

Cheers,
Graeme

Comment: his is what virtual functions are for

Comment: Virtual functions aren't my concern; it's overloading for every possible Msg class.

Comment: can you make msg polymorphic as well - and get rid of templates?  how many msg classes you have?

Comment: @aaa - do you mean give all Msg classes a common base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to use virtual functions (this seems to be a perfect use case for them actually, but I don't know about your message classes), you can use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename U>
struct Consumer
{
    template <typename T>
    void callback(T msg)
    { static_cast<U*>(this)->callback(msg); }
};


struct Client : Consumer<Client>
{
     void callback(Msg1 msg);
     void callback(Msg2 msg);
     void callback(Msg3 msg);
};
```

The problem, of course, is that you cannot store `Consumer` objects in a container any more. Since everything is compile time, the actual type of the client must be stored alongside the consumer object for the compiler to call the right callback function. Virtual functions allow you to wait until runtime for this...

Is there a reason not to have `Msg` classes polymorphic and use standard virtual functions (other than "I have to rewrite all the code and I cannot") ?

**EDIT** If your concern is about message classes, why not use something like that, assuming message classes implement a `DoSomething` member function: (this technique is known as *Type Erasure*)

```
struct AnyMsg
{
    template <typename Msg>
    AnyMsg(Msg x) : impl(newImpl(x)) {}

    void DoSomething() { impl->DoSomething(); }

private:
    struct Impl
    {
        virtual ~Impl() {}
        virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
    };

    // Probably better is std::unique_ptr if you have
    // C++0x. Or `boost::scoped_ptr`, but you have to
    // provide copy constructors yourself.
    boost::shared_ptr<Impl> impl;

    template <typename Msg>
    Impl* newImpl(Msg m)
    {
        class C : public Impl
        {
            void DoSomething() { x.DoSomething(); }
            Msg x;

        public:
            C(Msg x) : x(x) {}
        };

        return new C(m);
    }
};
```

You can customize the behavior of `newImpl` to get what you want (eg. default actions if there is no `DoSomething` member function in the message class, specialization for some message classes or anything else). This way, you implement `Msg` classes like you would have done with your template solution, and you have a unique facade that you can pass to the virtual functions in your client classes.

If the Message classes are going to be very different, and client classes may react differently to them, and you are going to have a lot of message classes, this begins to smell. Or perhaps you have a candidate for the ugly and scary [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: I think this wouldn't work since with your example you cannot have a container with 'just' `Consumer` objects ...

Comment: @Martin: Of course. I'm just exposing the "standard" alternative to virtual functions for delegating to a derived class.

Comment: This will be a framework where additional Msg classes should be easily plugged in. If I have to overload a function for every Msg object it could run into well over 100 in no time. That was what I saw the benefit of the templated base callback function, it would catch anything that wasn't overloaded in the client and therefore allow a new Client to be created with a new set of Msgs without changing the rest of the framework.

Comment: @MartinStettner: oops, sorry, I did delete my comment when I noticed this.

Comment: @Graeme: If the client and msg objects are only known at runtime, I'm afraid you have no choice but using virtual dispatch.

Comment: I agree about the last paragraph: Sending arbitrary messges to arbitrary recievers means mimicing a dynamic language (like Smalltalk or ObjectiveC) which somehow breaks the static OO concept of C++. There is nothing inherently wrong about this, but since C++ doesn't support it you will not get much support from the language for it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use virtual methods, the compiler would have to know statically (i.e. at compile time) which function to call. If you have different client objects in your container, there is now way the compiler could possibly know this. So I think there's no solution to your problem without using virtual methods (which are btw. exactly designed for this kind of situations...).

Of course you could alternatively using some `switch` statements for manually deriving the concrete type, but this is neither elegant nor efficient (and you would have to hardcode all possible client types ...)

**EDIT**

Personally, I'd implement some base message class containing a type code and implement a `switch` statement in the client class to handle different message types like:

```
struct MsgBase {
   int type;
};

struct Consumer {
   virtual void callback(MsgBase msg) { };
};

struct Client : public Consumer {
    void callback(MsgBase msg) {
        switch (msg.type) {
        case MSGTYPE1:
           callback((Msg1)msg);
           break;
        case MSGTYPE2:
           callback((Msg2)msg);
           break;
        // ...
        }
   }
   void callback(Msg1 msg) { /* ... */ }
   void callback(Msg2 msg) { /* ... */ }
};
```

You could also make `MsgBase` polymorphic (e.g. virtual destructor) and use `typeid` to differentiate (more elegant but slightly less efficient ...)

```
struct Client : public Consumer {
    void callback(MsgBase* msg) {
        if (typeid(*msg) == typeof(Msg1))
           callback(static_cast<Msg1*>(msg));
        else if (typeid(*msg) == typeof(Msg2))
           callback(static_cast<Msg2*>(msg));
    }
    // ...
 };
```

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to avoid having to writing an overloaded function for every Msg class?

Comment: Im afraid, yes. Think of it this way: When using the `Consumer` base class, the compiler knows nothing about your different client implementations. How could he possibly know if, for a given `Msg` type, the client implements an overloaded method if its only declared as template. I'd go with @aaa's suggestion and make the msg class either polymorphic or at least have some kind of type code. Then you can implement a switch statement in each client class and let the client decide, which messages to handle.

Answer (score 1):

This is always a difficult situation to make totally extensible, as is the case usually with the Visitor pattern.

You end up needing up to V*T implementations where V is the number of "visitors" and T is the number of types being visited and will probably end up having to use a mixture of visitor and class factory pattern.

visitors here would be your consumers
class factory would be used for the message types.

and your best way to make it totally extensible is to create new function "objects" for message/consumer pairs and a bit of double-dispatch to ensure the right one gets called.

In your case you have different messages come in and then you give them to your consumers who might handle them? So each message should have an identifiable "type" and your consumer 
should look up this type in a table to create a handler for it.

You can have one handler per type per consumer class.